# Out of the list of common materials, are composite ice hockey sticks customarily able to mix and match materials as desired?

Tags: ice-hockey

Common/customary materials for ice hockey sticks seem to include:

- Wood
- Fiberglass
- Aluminum
- Carbon Fiber
- Kevlar

While a lot of sites seem to kind of place sticks in two general categories, wood and composite, a lot of them kind of tend to stop there and just say that composite is better than wood.

My question is, between these sorts of materials, how free-form can you customarily be in making a standard hockey stick, in terms of both the number and the types of materials chosen?

For example, can you pick any one of these materials and use it as the sole material for a standard stick?  (Maybe the kevlar is a bad choice for that, but I'm not sure.)  Are there any materials on this list that don't play nice with each other?  Is it easy to pick any number (1-5) of the materials?

This is asking specifically about standard-ish, customary sticks, not anything too far off the beaten path.

Comment: Are you asking "is it generally possible to do this", or, "is it permissible under some set of rules"?  If the latter, what set of rules?  NHL?  NCAA? International?

Comment: @Joe It may be a bit open-ended.  If I have to choose though, International rules, combined with it also being considered within the realm of decent craftsmanship.

Comment: It's mostly that if you limit this to a particular league, you might get a decent answer. I suspect it's unlikely to get a good materials science answer here - we just don't have the experts in that field.

Comment: @Joe So there's not really a worldwide convention then - it just depends on the league?

Comment: I have no idea from a materials perspective.  There may well be.  I'm just saying - we have experts here who are familiar with various leagues' rules; hence, that's more likely what you'll get a good answer on.